# Get Process Load of current Windows Processes in %

Tags: windows, powershell, monitoring

I'd like to get the Process Load of all Processes currently active over a short period of time (1-2 seconds).

Basically it should be the same as the Windows Task Manager presents (Tab Processes -> Column CPU). Can someone tell me how to do this in Powershell - I already found some example and tried around myself but I am not happy with the results.

Thank you a lot.

Greets

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Get CPU Percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125950/powershell-get-cpu-percentage)

Comment: The only problem is that the answers given there do not solve my problem. Getting the CPU time used by a process is easy, but getting the same CPU % values as the taskmanager is kind of tricky.