# Compute CPU % for w3wp.exe in powershell

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I am developing a script which fetches CPU time for w3wp.exe i need to compute the actual CPU percentage used by the process and not CPU time, using get-process i get only the CPU time. Please let me know the computation steps for getting cpu percentage used just like how its displayed in task-bar using power-shell

Note: I dont want to use gwmi since script response is very slow. I want to use this app in a performance test enviornment and dont want to apply any load on processing.

```
 get-wmiobject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Get CPU Percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125950/powershell-get-cpu-percentage)

Comment: Please check my edit to the question

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. On my system, `Measure-Command { Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'w3wp.exe' } }` reports that using `Get-WmiObject` completed just under 400 milliseconds or 0.4 second. Do you experience a significantly higher execution time or it's just that's too slow for your purposes? (I should note that the first query took a long time for me, too).

Comment: @PeterK Thanks am developing this utility for a high performance machine with 16 cpu's which is tested with over 80k virtual users in load runner at one point in time. To query utilization on multiple cpu's takes time with gwmi :(

Comment: Thanks. My workstation has only 4 cores, that could explain the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using Get-Counter:

```
get-counter '\Process(powershell*)\% Processor Time'
```

Comment: Is the counter data 'CPU Time' ? or its the computer process utilized by a given process just like the data given in taskbar ?

Comment: It's percent CPU utilization of the core it's running on. To get the percentage of total CPU utilization like you see in Task Manager, divide that by the number of cores.

Comment: Hi, How do i get Process time by adding process id as the filter instead of process name, because a IIS application has several app-pools with the same process name w3wp